# A bit of confusion on maximum value of modulus of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I was presented with a problem that seems obvious, but I'm having trouble coming up with a proper solution:

Consider a polynomial $p$ on the complex plane, and focus on the unit circle. Show that if $p(1) = 1$, $p'(1) \in \mathrm{R}$ and $ \; p'(1) <0$ , then $|p(z)|$ cannot have a local maximum at $1$ (with respect to the circle, not the whole plane).

edit: I didnt't include the positivity assumption.

Comment: What about $p(z) = -1 - z$?

Comment: You need more because $p(z)=-z$ satisfies conditions; if you know $p(1) \ge 0$ or non-real then conclusion holds by Jack's lemma

Comment: Thanks, I realised I needed another assumption - I've also noticed that it now follows directly from definition of derivative, if we focus on the real axis.